# Getting data from an instance of a model in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, dynamic, models

I am pretty new to Rails and I am lost right now.
I was following the [blog tutorial](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html), utilizing the information to create a different application which is kinda similar.
Well, what I want (in SQL language) is:
`select planned from hourplans where area_id = 2 and time = '9:00:00'`
There are 4 Models in my Application (it is basically the application from the blog tutorial put twice on the same website):
**Productions (which can have multiple downtimes)** [Production] --1-------N-- [Downtime]
`class Production < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :downtimes,  dependent: :destroy
  validates :items, presence: true
end`
*Production has the Attributes: Date(date), Time(time), Area(text) and Items(integer)*

`class Downtime < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :production
end`
*Downtime has the Attributes Username(text), Category(text), Machine(text), Station(text), Minutes(integer) and Details(text)*
**Areas (which can have multiple hourplans)** [Area] --1-------N-- [Hourplan]
`class Area < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :hourplans, dependent: :destroy
    validates :title, presence: true
end`
*Area has the Attributes Title(text), Text(text)*
`class Hourplan < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :area
end`

*Hourplan has the Attributes Time(time), Cycle(decimal), Minutes(integer) and Planned(integer)*

So for example there is an object for the production from 9:00 to 10:00, production has a field called "area" which has the value 'area2'.
And there is also a object of Area which has the title 'Area2' which is related to an object Hourplan that has a field called 'planned' with the value of items that are planned(like 600) from 9:00 to 10:00.
How can I fetch that data into the show-page of the production from 9:00 to 10:00?

I can't get it to transfer.

I tried something like:
`<% area2.hourplans.where("time = 09:00").select(:planned) %>`

but that didnt work.

Then I thought I had to set the object of the model to a variable first, so I tried:
`<% area = Area.find_by title: @production.area %>`

But I just dont get it. I dont know whether this worked or not. But how can I get to the hourplans now? Those are related to the Areas

I also tried: 
`<%= Hourplan.select("planned").where("time = 9:00 AND area_id = 2") %>`
and that just gave me:
`#<Hourplan::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x50c23e0>` and I dont know what that means, I thought I would have gotten a value out of the SQL Table, like '600'

I hope I made myself clear and understandable. If you have any questions please let me know. I would really appreciate your help, I was looking through the official guides but I can't really find what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try to replace

```
<%= Hourplan.select("planned").where("time = 9:00 AND area_id = 2") %>
```

by

```
<%= Hourplan.where("time = '9:00' AND area_id = 2").first.planned %>
```

Indeed, the `where` method returns a relation, which represents (roughly) the result of a SQL query. But you know that an SQL query may or may not return a single line. Generally, there are several rows returned. That's why you'll want to add `first`, to get only the first Hourplan object.

Comment: Hey thank you for your answer.
This has given me:
`ODBC::Error: 37000 (102) [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near ':'.: EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT TOP (1) [hourplans].* FROM [hourplans] WHERE (time = 9:00 AND area_id = 2) ORDER BY [hourplans].[id] ASC'`
did i forget something?

Comment: Yes, change `9:00` by `'9:00'`. I did not check your where condition, just explained how to use a relation. You'll have to get the correct syntax by youself.